# подскажите пожалуйста по тесту по питону

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано натуральное число n  . Напишите программу, которая печатает таблицу сложения для всех чисел от 1 до n в соответствии с примером

мой код такой

не могу понять как сделать таблицы  в столбик ,print() в конце добавил, end='' в принте в втором цикле пробовал убирать , но тогда везде будут двойные пробелы и тоже не зачтет

```
n=int(input())
for i in range (1, 10):
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        print(j,'+',i,'=',j+i,end='')
    print()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

у вас циклы местами перепутаны, поэтому такой дикий результат, да и в `print` некорректный вывод

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        print(f'{i} + {j} = {i + j}')
    print()
```

Answer (score 2):

просто поменяйте местами два цикла

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, n+1):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        print(i,'+',j,'=',j+i)
    print()
```

Comment: тогда столбы меняются местами ,вместо 1+3 получяится 3+1,тоже не зачтет

Comment: @Tommy Valachi, ну так в `print` переставьте местами `i` и `j` :)

Comment: спаасибо огромное , все получилось , извиняюсь за тупняк с переменными, 2 суток думал , а можно обьяснить что за магия бесовская произошла что от перемены циклов получилось все? я принцип не понял